# Default child state with same url as parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have app with many main states, one of them is user profile:

```
  $stateProvider.state('profile', {
    url: '/profile/',
    templateUrl: 'profile/profile.html',
    controller: 'Profile',
  });
```

But this is just an container for nested pages with different profile settings. It's template only contains main menu and `ui-view` for nested states. Controller is only for that menu handling.

One of nested views should be default url and have same URL as parent, so there shouldn't be any suffixes added into url, but I can't achieve that.

Here's what I tried:

```
  $stateProvider.state('profile.details', {
      url: '',
      templateUrl: 'profile/details.html',
      controller: 'ProfileDetails',
  });
```

this is not working at all, at url `/profile/` only menu appears and an empty `ui-view` element. Second approach:

```
  $stateProvider.state('profile.details', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'profile/details.html',
      controller: 'ProfileDetails',
  });
```

This matches on url `/profile//` (with 2 slashes at end). At url `/profile/` there is still menu and empty `ui-view` element.

How can I achieve that result? Is this even possible using angular-ui-router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your parent state abstract. This will prevent from going into that state, and force to go to child states only. Abstract states are perfect as templates for child ones. Also get rid of url:

```
$stateProvider.state('profile', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'profile/profile.html',
    controller: 'Profile',
  });
```

Now for your child state define absolute URL

```
$stateProvider.state('profile.details', {
      url: '^profile',
      templateUrl: 'profile/details.html',
      controller: 'ProfileDetails',
  });
```

That should work.

Comment: Why should I get rid of url? That way other child states can't inherit it.

Comment: That is the clue. You can overwrite is as you like. This should not be a problem as long as you do not have a great amount of child states.